# How can I deploy an exploded web app through WebLogic 11g administrative console?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I need to deploy a web applicataion as an exploded archive (instead of .war) due to some legacy servlet path location code used in it (ServletContext.getRealPath()). I only have web-based admin console access to the WebLogic 11g server that I intend to deploy to. However, I can't figure how to do it. I see an option for deploying archives, but not directories.

Thanks!

Comment: i did not saw initially that you have only web admin console...so i deleted prev answer

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/overview.html

"WebLogic Server supports deployments that are packaged either as archive files using the jar utility, or **as exploded archive directories**".

Answer (score 1):

The link 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/deployment/overview.html
is for version 8.1. In newer versions this option does not exist in the admin console (production mode).

The only way is if you somehow access the operating system, or ask somebody to, unzip the war file in some place and then install from that directory (through admin console). You can also upload the war using admin console, and then in the uploaded directory ask to whom as access to SO to unzip it in that place.

You can also try some ninja stuff like: upload the war that you want to expand. Then make another war that contains code that unzips the war you want to expand.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem in weblogic11gR1,In  admin console in configuration tab -->web-App container click the option "Archived Real path enabled" so that you can access the `servletcontext.getRealpath()`.