# Can we deploy a directory application on WebLogic?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic8.x

We have an old application running on a WebLogic 8.1.5.0.

In this version, we can see that the application has been configured as a directory (which has classes, css, images, htmls), but No WAR, JAR or EAR found for this app.

PFB the extract from config.xml

Application Name="abc" Path="/wls_domains/flret/admin/applications"   StagingMode="nostage" TwoPhase="true">

```
    <WebAppComponent Name="abc" Targets="admin" URI="abc"/>
```

Now, we need to migrate this application to WebLogic 10.3.6.0.

New Weblogic is not allowing us to deploy an application other than WAR, EAR or JAR.

Also, config.xml structure is completely different for new weblogic.

```
<name>XYZ</name>

<target>XYZ_cluster</target>

<module-type>war</module-type>

<source-path>servers/admin/upload/XYZ.war</source-path>

<security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
```

Is it something related to weblogic versions and feature available to deploy a directory?

Can someone plz suggest can I complete this deployment or any other way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an 'Exploded Archive' app, which modern versions of weblogic do not support. You need to upgrade to a modern format, or put it directly on the filesystem of the app server.

(see: [How can I deploy an exploded web app through WebLogic 11g administrative console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431425/how-can-i-deploy-an-exploded-web-app-through-weblogic-11g-administrative-console))

Comment: The directory is already in place on new app server. But how can I access that directory/files using an URL, just like we do for a web application?
e.g: Suppose the exploded archive is "XYZ", I want to access that using URL like "http://hostname:port/XYZ/index.jsp"

Comment: You should be able to look at it in the Deployments section of the admin console - there will be a tab that shows how to access it via the web, if it's set up correctly.